# create MSI that can be installed in console per user and per machine

Tags: windows-installer, wix3

I'm using WIX v3 to create installer for our app. We already have an MSI that can be installed with standard wizard that gives user options to install it only for them or for all users.

Now clients said that they want to install it in console with

```
msiexec /i <app.msi> ALLUSERS=2 /qn
```

So they want to install it for each user silently and separately without any further interaction with installer.

What is best practice to implement .msi for theese requirements? Is ALLUSERS parameter is obsolete? Maybe there is special tool that can make creation of .msi easier than notepad++?

I've tried to rewrite old .wxs file with condition for ALLUSERS parameter, but couldn't set installation directory depending on it.
Tried to create custom parameter that depends on ALLUSERS parameter.